# Triangulate square mesh randomly

Tags: modifiers

I am using blender to triangulate a mesh that I want to use for a physics simulation (outside blender). For that, I want to randomly remesh it. The triangulate modifier is not enough, as there is a preferent edge direction, which I want to avoid.
[image]

Ideally, adding random vertices inside the quad and force a remeshing algorithm to use this points would work, but I have no idea how to do it or if it is even possible in blender.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new shapekey for your plane.  Enter edit mode on that shapekey.
2. Use transform->randomize operation.
3. Use a triangulate faces operation.  In operator panel, specify "shortest diagonal."
4. Leave edit mode and delete your shapekey.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the boundary needs to be the same (can be refined, but I still need to have a square)

Comment: @jjcasmar the boundary will be the same.  The reason you're using a shapekey is so that your randomization won't affect the original shape.  You're using it only to randomize what the shortest diagonal for each quad is.

Answer (score 5):

**`bmesh` Script.**

[image]

Runs thru every quad in the mesh and makes it into two triangles via a random choice of making edge connecting  either face verts 0 to 2, or 1 to 3.

Test script. Randomly triangulates the active object in OBJECT mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import choice

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

quads = [f for f in bm.faces if len(f.verts) == 4]

for q in quads:
    i = choice(range(2))
    bmesh.ops.connect_verts(
            bm,
            verts=[q.verts[i], q.verts[i + 2]],
            )

bm.to_mesh(me)
```

Comment: How long have you been using Python? And how long did it take you to learn it?

Comment: Since circa the mid naughties.  Had coded in other languages, bit like a musical instrument, once you learn one you pick up another reasonably quickly. Still learning tho.  Ironically I'm not sure how much sites like this help. Had to nut things out in the old days.