# Duplicated vertices created by bmesh.ops.bisect_plane

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh, bisect

I want to get a mesh's bisected surface's vertices and edges. I tried to bisect a sphere using bmesh.ops.bisect_plane.

```
import bpy
from  bpy import context
import bmesh

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.05)
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)


origin = (0,0,0)
axis = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]
dir = 1

geo = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom = bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:], dist = 0, plane_co = origin, plane_no = axis[dir], clear_outer = False, clear_inner = False)['geom_cut']
print('geo len:',len(geo))

verts = [v for v in geo if isinstance(v, bmesh.types.BMVert)]        
edges = [e for e in geo if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMEdge)]        

print('newverts len:',len(verts))
print('newedges len:',len(edges))

for v in verts:
    print(v.co[0],',',v.co[1],',',v.co[2])
```

Everything seems ok. But, when I bisect using XZ or YZ plane, the number of vertices and edges created are different. Besides, there are many very close vertices created. For example,

```
-3.91155481338501e-08 , 0.0 , -0.04999999701976776
-5.314408468848342e-08 , 0.0 , 0.04999999701976776
-2.421438694000244e-08 , 0.0 , -0.04999999701976776
-3.757856248398639e-08 , 0.0 , 0.04999999701976776
-1.6298145055770874e-08 , 0.0 , -0.04999999701976776
-2.71779967420116e-08 , 0.0 , 0.04999999701976776
-1.0710209608078003e-08 , 0.0 , -0.04999999701976776
-1.9217743840727053e-08 , 0.0 , 0.04999999701976776
-6.51925802230835e-09 , 0.0 , -0.05000000074505806
-1.2469362431488662e-08 , 0.0 , 0.04999999701976776
-3.14321368932724e-09 , 0.0 , -0.05000000074505806
```

After removed all these "duplicated" vertices, the number of vertices created is then same when bisecting on both planes.

Is there anything wrong in the code? Or is this normal?

Comment: The issue occurs at the "north and south pole" vertices. where, for default sphere each have 32 linked edges.   Added to this the default sphere already has edges exactly where you are bisecting (for each axis)  Would say what you are seeing is "normal" and within the precision of blender, and as noted can be cleared by removing doubles.   For a UV sphere could instead choose edges where both verts are x~=0 for ZY plane, etc.

Comment: Thanks for let me know. This happens on Ico Sphere too.

Comment: NP. Would make for an interesting routine to instead select all verts lying on cut plane pick one and walk edges until get back to it.   Which may require cutting across a face if two verts selected without an edge between them [akin to this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214722/15543)  etc. However prob much easier to bisect and remove doubles.